# How to reuse a set of components on Data Flow taks of SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

Hi I am a newbie in SSIS. I wrote a sample package in which I configured a Data Flow Task something like shown below

```
 Output from a OLE DB Source
      |(error output)
 (Script Task )
      |    
 (Sort Task )
      |
 (OLE DB Destination)
```

From another path in the same Data Flow task can I add the output to Script task something like shown below

```
 Output from a OLE DB Source   Output from a another OLE DB Source
                    |(erroro/p)       |(error o/p)
                     | \\\\\          ///|
                         (Script Task )
                            |    
                        (Sort Task )
                            |
                       (OLE DB Destination)
```

My intention here is to reuse the mapping made for handling errors in the Same Data Flow Task.

Any sugesstions?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to combine error output from different sources, you can use `Union All` transformation within `Data Flow task` to combine the output which can then be passed onto other transformations or destinations. Please refer the below screenshot in which the data flow task has two flat file sources. The successful rows are combined using the Union All transformation **Success rows** and then passed onto the Success transformations and destination. Similarly, the error output rows are combined using the Union All transformation **Error rows** and then passed onto the Error transformations and destination.

**`Note:`** Here both the flat file sources use the same file layout.

Hope that helps.

[image: 1]

Comment: This was really useful combining error ouputs. But I am looking for a way in which i can resuse components for handling errors.

Comment: In the above case I want to redirect errors from Flat File 1 and Flat File 2 to Components (error rows to error), here these components should handle handle errors form two sources but dont combine the results.